# In Symfony 2, how do I handle routing for multiple domains?

Tags: symfony, routes, wildcard

I have my app setup to use 3 subdomains, I also have 2 domains that point to the same app, giving me this set of FQDNs

admin.domain1.com, admin.domain2.com

www.domain1.com, www.domain2.com

kiosk.domain1.com, kiosk.domain2.com

In routing.yml I can set up the host / resource keys to point those domains at the relevant bundle, but I can only do it for one of the domains at a time.

```
incompass_admin:
    host:     admin.domain1.com
    resource: "@IncompassAdminBundle/Resources/config/routes.yml"

incompass_web:
    host:     www.domain1.com
    resource: "@IncompassWebBundle/Resources/config/routes.yml"

incompass_kiosk:
    host:     kiosk.domain1.com
    resource: "@IncompassKioskBundle/Resources/config/routes.yml"
```

When I try something like this

```
incompass_kiosk_1:
    host:     kiosk.domain1.com
    resource: "@IncompassKioskBundle/Resources/config/routes.yml"

incompass_kiosk_2:
    host:     kiosk.domain2.com
    resource: "@IncompassKioskBundle/Resources/config/routes.yml"
```

The second domain is the only one that is recognised, kiosk.domain1.com throws an exception: No route found for "GET /"

Is there a way to either set the domain as a wildcard in routing.yml, or to point 2 different routes to the same resource?

edit: I've also tried to have

```
IncompassKioskBundle/Resources/config/routes_1.yml
IncompassKioskBundle/Resources/config/routes_2.yml
```

and

```
IncompassKioskBundle/Resources/config/routes.yml
IncompassRoutingBundle/Resources/config/kiosk_routes.yml
```

where the names of the routes in the 2 files are different e.g.

```
// routes.yml
domain_one_kiosk_scanning:
    type: annotation
    prefix: /
    resource: Incompass\KioskBundle\Controller\ScanningController

domain_one_kiosk_printing:
    type: annotation
    prefix: /print
    resource: Incompass\KioskBundle\Controller\PrintingController 

// kiosk_routes.yml
domain_two_kiosk_scanning:
    type: annotation
    prefix: /
    resource: Incompass\KioskBundle\Controller\ScanningController

domain_two_kiosk_printing:
    type: annotation
    prefix: /print
    resource: Incompass\KioskBundle\Controller\PrintingController
```

That did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use placeholders in routes, so try something like this:

```
incompass_kiosk:
    host:     "kiosk.{domain}.com"
    resource: "@IncompassKioskBundle/Resources/config/routes.yml"
    requirements:
        domain: domain1|domain2
    defaults: { domain: domain1 }
```

You could alternatively handle this in your .htaccess or virtual host configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the response. When I try this I get **An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Some mandatory parameters are missing ("domain") to generate a URL for route**

Comment: You may need to also define a default. See above.